# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'void org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory.<init>(org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jMarkerFactory)'

Tags: logging, apache-flink, log4j2, slf4j

im currently on a apache flink job which provides log4j2 as default logging implementation at its runtime ([see here](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.16/docs/deployment/advanced/logging/)).
For flexibility SLF4J should be used.
Running the whole job in flink logs properly, but during Unit Test using JUnit5 there are no logs shown in IntelliJ.

For debugging purposes it would be necessary to have the log statements also during unit test execution.

I have made a minimal [example project](https://github.com/iLem0n/minmal-logging-example)

**The Problem:**

I have drilled it down to inclusion of `org.apache.flink:flink-test-utils:1.16.1` which results to the following:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'void org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory.<init>(org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jMarkerFactory)'
    at org.apache.logging.slf4j.SLF4JServiceProvider.initialize(SLF4JServiceProvider.java:54)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.bind(LoggerFactory.java:183)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.performInitialization(LoggerFactory.java:170)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getProvider(LoggerFactory.java:455)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory(LoggerFactory.java:441)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:390)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:416)
    at bmw.pcmasfd.zip.flink.udf.BuildGroupContextTest.<clinit>(BuildGroupContextTest.java:27)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:315)
```

**Context:**

```
IntelliJ IDEA 2022.3.3 RC (Ultimate Edition)
Java version: 11.0.18 (Azul)
Flink version: 1.16.1
```

**pom.xml**(v1):

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>minimal-logging-example</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>

        <flink.version>1.16.1</flink.version>

    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.26</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Flink -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-streaming-java</artifactId>
            <version>1.16.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-runtime</artifactId>
            <version>${flink.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-core</artifactId>
            <version>${flink.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- TESTING -->
        <!--
        only including this dependency leads to:
        java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'void org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory.<init>(org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jMarkerFactory)'
        -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-test-utils</artifactId>
            <version>${flink.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
      
        <!-- Logging -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.17.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-slf4j2-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.20.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Testing -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.13.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <version>5.9.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.skyscreamer</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsonassert</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

EDIT:
**pom.xml**(v2):

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>minimal-logging-example</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>

        <flink.version>1.16.1</flink.version>

    </properties>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>log4j-bom</artifactId>
                <version>2.20.0</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.26</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Flink -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-streaming-java</artifactId>
            <version>1.16.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-runtime</artifactId>
            <version>${flink.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-core</artifactId>
            <version>${flink.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- TESTING -->
        <!--
        only including this dependency leads to:
        java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'void org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory.<init>(org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jMarkerFactory)'
        -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-test-utils</artifactId>
            <version>${flink.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>log4j-slf4j-impl</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <!--
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-test-utils-junit</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-streaming-java</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <classifier>tests</classifier>
        </dependency>
        -->

        <!-- Logging -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-slf4j2-impl</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Testing -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.13.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <version>5.9.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.skyscreamer</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsonassert</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `flink-test-utils` dependency pulls an old version of [`log4j-slf4j-impl`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.logging.log4j/log4j-slf4j-impl) as transitive dependency (through [`flink-test-utils-junit`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.flink/flink-test-utils-junit/1.16.1)).

This is probably a bug and you should report it: the authors forgot to put the Log4j2 dependencies in the `test` scope. Libraries should not include a logging backend as `compile/runtime` dependency and leave that choice to the library user.

In the meantime you can simply add some exclusions:

```xml
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
    <artifactId>flink-test-utils</artifactId>
    <version>1.16.1</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
    <exclusions>
      <exclusion>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
      </exclusion>
      <exclusion>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
      </exclusion>
      <exclusion>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-slf4j-impl</artifactId>
      </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
  </dependency>
```

**Remark:** The versions of `log4j-core` and `log4j-slf4j2-impl` should be in sync (right now `log4j-core` pulls `log4j-api` 2.17.1 into your project, whereas `log4j-slf4j2-impl` requires version 2.20.0). The easiest way is to use [`log4j-bom`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.logging.log4j/log4j-bom) in your dependency management.

**Remark 2:**

> For flexibility SLF4J should be used.

That is a common misconception/anachronism: when SLF4J was introduced, it offered all the features of Logback, while allowing users to use a legacy logging backend (Log4j 1.x, `java.util.logging`).

When the [Log4j 2.x API](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/api-separation.html) was introduced about 10 years later, it offered all the features of Log4j 2.x Core, while allowing users to use other logging backends (Logback, `java.util.logging`).

By using SLF4J with Log4j 2.x Core, you limit the available logging API methods, while you don't really increase the choice of logging backends.

**Edit:** Another problem with the `flink-test-utils` dependency is that it depends on the tests jar of `flink-core` and `flink-runtime`, which contains a [`log4j2-test.properties`](https://github.com/apache/flink/blob/master/flink-runtime/src/test/resources/log4j2-test.properties) file. This is the file that disables logging during testing.

Now you have several workarounds:

1. The test jars usually contain code only useful for the project itself. You can try excluding `flink-core` and `flink-runtime` from `flink-test-utils`,
2. Add a `log4j2-test.properties` file to your test resources and rely on the fact that **usually** test launchers place the test classes on the classpath **before** their dependencies. Unfortunately the properties configuration format has a higher priority than all other formats, so you can't just use another format.
3. Add a `log4j2-test.*` configuration file (e.g. `log4j2-test.xml`) to your test resources and a `log4j2.component.properties` file with content:

   ```
   log4j2.configurationFile=log4j2-test.xml
   ```

Comment: Hello @Piotr, thanks for clarification, but even without the flexibility I need a working logging ^^ 
I made the changes (in the question and GitHub)
Now I don't get an exception anymore but also there is nothing shown in the logs now.

Comment: @PeterC.Glade, my remark about flexibility was: you don't loose flexibility if you use Log4j 2.x API directly. Regarding the JUnit tests: `flink-test-utils` has more surprises than the one I anticipated, I edited the answer accordingly.

Comment: Thanks you very much for your help and your detailed explanations. I have now added `log4j2.component.properties` and `log4j2-test.properties` file to the project and only included log4j2-core and log4j2-api as a dependency and it works now perfectly ;)